# How to find out what stack frame EBP belongs to

Tags: windows, ollydbg

i'm newbie to all the subject of RE so this question may sound easy.
on OllyDbg i see a lot of references to EBP & i can not understand to which stack frame does EBP belongs to, since there are many pointers to SS:

[image]

Comment: When `ebp` is referenced, it usually belongs to the stack frame of the current function. At the beginning of the function, you usually will see a `push ebp` and a `mov esp, ebp` to set up the stack frame for the current function.

Comment: so in the image i posted the EBP belongs to the function i'm in & that function calls to more multiple functions?

Comment: Most likely, yes. Inside those functions, they will also `push ebp` and `mov esp, ebp` to set up their own stack frames.

Answer (score 2):

The Current ebp points to the previous ebp
and by inference the call that setup the previous ebp

in windbg with a 32 bit binary this script will walk the stack you can use follow in dump in ollydbg to do the same

```
r $t0 = @eip
r $t1 = @ebp
.while (@$t1 !=0) 
{
    .printf "eip = %08x\tebp = %08x\t callee = %y\n" , @$t0 ,@$t1,poi(@$t1+4)
    r $t0 = poi(@$t1+4)
    r $t1 = poi(@$t1)
}
```

executing the script

```
0:000> $$>a< e:\stackwalk.wds
eip = 006a163a  ebp = 0023fa54   callee = calc!_initterm_e+0x1a1 (006b219a)
eip = 006b219a  ebp = 0023fae4   callee = kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe (7659ed6c)
eip = 7659ed6c  ebp = 0023faf0   callee = ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70 (77d237eb)
eip = 77d237eb  ebp = 0023fb30   callee = ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b (77d237be)
eip = 77d237be  ebp = 0023fb48   callee = 00000000
0:000> k
ChildEBP RetAddr
0023fa54 006b219a calc!WinMain+0x5
0023fae4 7659ed6c calc!_initterm_e+0x1a1
0023faf0 77d237eb kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
0023fb30 77d237be ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
0023fb48 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
0:000>
```